Minimum dimensions of information required to find the positions of straight wires
An infinite straight wire creates a magnetic field that is inversely proportional to the distance to the wire, and proportional to the current flowing through it. For simplicity, let us say that the magnetic field is $B=\dfrac{kI}{r}\hat{\phi}$.
Magnetic field of straight wire:

So my question is that:
If there are $n$ wires randomly placed in a 3d space, what is the minimum dimension $m_n$ of (magnetic field) information required to accurately calculate the position and the current of each wires?
+EDIT: I added the definition of "dimension" at the end.
For example, if $n=1$, $m_1=1$ because:
Zero-dimension-case:

There are more than two cases possible if you only have 0 dimension of information, therefore $m_1 \ge 0$, and
One-dimension-case:

A line of information can place the wire accurately, so $m_1 =1$.
**EDIT: Definition of Dimension:
The position of the wires can be determined with an information dimension $m$ if:
For all $m$-dimensional object $S$ with a finite $m$-dimensional volume(length for $m=1$,area for $m=2$, and so on...)  $V$ ($V>0$), one can determine the position and the current of the wires.
Please let me know if there are better ways to define "dimension"s.

Not sure what you mean by "dimension". I suppose that measuring the magnetic field $B(X_n)$ in several positions $X_n$ is enough to solve uniquely, where $n$ is a function of the number of wires etc.

@user619894 I added the definition of "dimension" at the end, thanks for pointing that out! + Is it possible to figure out the positions with a finite number of information, even when $n$ is large enough?

I believe a finite number of points is enough if the wires are straight. Suppose you know there is 1 infinite wire, defined by 5 degrees of freedom (direction and offset from origin), and 1 d.o.f for the strength, total of 6 unknowns.
